# Filter list of dictionaries with another list of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a large dataset (list of dictionaries - I will call it ds) and I would need to filter it with another list of dictionaries (I will call it filters).

I am using another question's dummy example as base for mine, sadly couldn't find an answer:

**EDIT: multiple element with same make and model exists**

```
ds = [
  {'make': 'Audi', 'model': 'A3', 'transmission': 'Manual'},
  {'make': 'Audi', 'model': 'A3', 'transmission': 'Automatic'},
  {'make': 'Audi', 'model': 'A1', 'transmission': 'Automatic'},
  {'make': 'Seat', 'model': 'Acura', 'transmission': 'Manual'},
  {'make': 'Seat', 'model': 'LEON', 'transmission': 'Manual'},
  {'make': 'Skoda', 'model': 'Octavia', 'transmission': 'Manual'},
]

filters = [
  {'make': 'Audi', 'model': 'A3'},
  {'make': 'Seat', 'model': 'LEON'},
  {'make': 'Skoda', 'model': 'Octavia'},
]
```

Wanted output:

```
ds_filtered = [
  {'make': 'Audi', 'model': 'A3', 'transmission': 'Manual'},
  {'make': 'Audi', 'model': 'A3', 'transmission': 'Automatic'},
  {'make': 'Seat', 'model': 'LEON', 'transmission': 'Manual'},
  {'make': 'Skoda', 'model': 'Octavia', 'transmission': 'Manual'},
]
```

Here is the code I wrote so far, but I would like to avoid loop, as the dataset is big and I would like the process to be more efficient:

```
ds_filtered = []
for f in filters:
    ds_filtered += [d for d in ds if (d['make'] == f['make'] and d['model'] == f['model'])]

print(ds_filtered)
```

Comment: no and no. It is not sorted and I do not use pandas. I could sort it though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've realized, your approach is quite inefficient, because it must search the whole `ds` list to look for matches for every filter. The first two answers have a similar problem.

In these cases you can often get a big speed up by converting one of the lists to a dictionary or a set. That way you only need to scan each list once.

1. Here is some simple code that works if each make/model is only in `ds` once;

```
dds = {(d['make'], d['model']): d for d in ds}
ds_filtered = [
    dds[d['make'], d['model']] 
    for d in filters
]
```

2. If you may have duplicates in `ds` but not in `filters`, you could switch it around like this:

```
fs = {(d['make'], d['model']) for d in filters}
ds_filtered = [
    d 
    for d in ds 
    if (d['make'], d['model']) in fs
]
```

Note that the second one creates a `set` to hold the info on all the filters. Unlike a `list`, this can be searched instantaneously to test each item in `ds` (similar to a `dict` lookup).

3. If you may have duplicates in both `ds` and `filters`, or if you need to repeat this several times with different lists of filters, then you need to create a lookup dictionary that groups multiple elements from `ds` by make and model. That is a little more complicated, but not too hard:

```
# make a dictionary with (make, model) as the key and
# a list of all matching items from `ds` as the value
dds = {}
for d in ds:
    # add an empty list to the dictionary if needed,
    # then append the current element
    dds.setdefault((d['make'], d['model']), []).append(d)

# find all the elements that match each filter
ds_filtered = [
    d
    for f in filters
    for d in dds[f['make'], f['model']] 
    # if some filters may not have matches, use this instead:
    # for d in dds.get((f['make'], f['model']), [])
]
```

Any of the solutions here will require `len(ds) + len(filters)` steps. The other solutions require `len(ds) * len(filters)` steps.

Comment: Matthias, sorry but this solution does not work with my actual ds because your solution does not allows for multiple lines with the same make+model to exists. Any other great idea?

Comment: @RenauV I was wondering if that would be an issue. The second one above should work if you don't have any duplicate filters and only need to process one batch of filters. But I've also posted a third version that can handle duplicates in both lists. The third one can also be used to quickly process multiple batches of filters. The second one would have to completely scan `ds` once for each batch of filters, but the third can reuse the `dds` dictionary to quickly process each new batch.

Comment: In my case, I cannot have duplicates in the filers, the #2 was perfect.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use a 'loop' then 'filter' works too, assuming you can find some safe way to hash make+model (I've used concatenation this might risk collisions)

```
filtered = list(filter(lambda elem: elem['make']+elem['model'] in [f['make']+f['model'] for f in filters], ds))
```

Comment: Usage of Python reserved keywords is not recommended. Could you use someother varialbe name instead of ```filter['make']``` ?

Answer (score -2):

Pretty easy. First loop over the ds and then loop over the filter to see if any matches.

```
result = []
 for i in ds:
     for j in filters:
         if j['make'] == i['make'] and j['model'] == i['model']:
             result.append(i)
             break
```

Comment: I think that's what the OP did in his solution.

Comment: It is the solution I present in my question - I would like it without loops (for efficiency reasons).